# How do I import a Rust file in a nested folder?

Tags: rust, module

I'm trying to separate my files for better project management:

```
src/   
|-main.rs   
|-entities/   
|--paddle.rs
```

Now, I'm trying to import my paddle.rs in my main.rs:
paddle.rs:

```
fn setup(){
  
}
```

How should I import it? I tried `use`, `mod`... none seems to work. I've read the Rust book but can't figure out how it's supposed to work!

Answer (score 2):

You need to add a `mod.rs` file to your `entities` folder with the following content:

```rust
pub mod paddle;
```

Make sure your `setup` function in `paddle.rs` is public:

```rust
pub fn setup() {...}
```

Then you can use your new module in `main.rs`:

```rust
mod entities;

fn main() {
  entities::paddle::setup();
}
```

Find more [here](https://doc.rust-lang.org/rust-by-example/mod/split.html).

Comment: Welp... I've read somewhere that the "mod.rs" is not necessary anymore, since file names act as modules definitions... But that does the trick, thank you!

Comment: It means you can use `src/entities.rs` instead of `src/entities/mod.rs`. But `paddle.rs` still has to be under `src/entities/`.